# Rails complex query first ascending, then descending

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, postgresql

so, I need to make a query which would work like this:

first, it would display elements, which have a date attribute "end_date" bigger than the current date, and the "release_date" attribute lower than the current date (example: today is the 15th of September, end_date is the 20th and release is the 12th). These elements are "active".

After displaying those, I would like to display past elements by descending order - past elements are those, who have "end_date" lower than the current date.

I would appreciate any help with building this query. Thanks!

P.S. I'm using PostgreSQL, Ruby 2.2.0 and Rails 4.2.1

Comment: Your question is vague. If you select rows with `end_date > current_date`, there are no elements with `end_date < current_date` to sort on.

Answer (score 0):

One of options is to make two queries and then merge ActiveRecord::Relation objects. Maybe not so efficient (2 queries), but easy to understand and refactor.

```
@relevant_elements = Element.where('end_date > :current_date AND release_date < :current_date', current_date: Date.today).order('end_date ASC')
@past_elements = Element.where('end_date < :current_date', current_date: Date.today).order('end_date DESC')
@elements = @relevant_elements.merge(@past_elements)
```

Comment: The result is an array without elements :(

Comment: Check every query alone. Also provide schema.rb. Maybe we don't understand each other.